# Scope of an Object in a Loop

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, scope, breadth-first-search

I have a simple algorithm which returns a list of lists, where each inner list contains the nodes on a different level of a binary tree. I'm having trouble understanding how to "reset" the scope of my inner list (e.g. see below).

My tree is a simple toy tree like so:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *left, *right;
}
```

I use a simple bfs that should return a list of lists. I try to create a new list on each of the loops, but I'm not sure how to "clear" the list and start a new one.

```
std::vector< std::vector<Node *> > build_lists(Node *root) {
    std::vector< std::vector<Node *> > result;

    Node *newline = new Node { std::numeric_limits<int>::min(), nullptr, nullptr };

    std::deque<int> q;
    q.push_back(root);
    q.push_back(newline);


    Node *tmp;
    std::vector<Node *> inner;    // HERE IS WHERE IS SET THE FIRST INNER VECTOR
    while(!q.empty()) {
        tmp = q.front();
        q.pop_front();
        if (tmp == newline) {
            result.push_back(inner);
            std::vector<Node *> inner; // HERE IS WHERE I TRY TO ''RESET'' THE VECTOR
            if (!q.empty())
                q.push_back(newline);
        } else {
            inner.push_back(tmp);
            if (tmp->left)
                q.push_back(tmp->left);
            if (tmp->right)
                q.push_back(tmp->right);
        }
    }
}
```

Clearly, I have failed to understand scope and some basic language features. If anyone could help point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Didn't down vote. By list you mean `inner`?

Comment: @gsamaras yes. sorry, vector I guess here.

Comment: Declaring a second object name "inner" doesn't do anything to the first object -- it just means you have two objects on the stack with the same name (a thing that is legal to do in C++ but generally frowned upon as it will cause confusion).  To reset the vector you should instead call inner.clear();

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Stupid question I guess, but why doesn't `inner.clear()` clear the vector that I've pushed onto the `result` vector?

Comment: Because push_back makes a copy of inner and pushes that copy into the result vector.  (C++ is different in that way from other languages like Java, where everything is passed by reference; in C++ you also commonly pass objects by-value, which involves making a copy of the object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reset a variable by declaring it again, which is what your code is doing. You now have a second variable with the same name, that for the duration of the second variable that name points to the second variable.

Instead you need to use a method to clear the first variable.

`vector` does have a [method to reset it's contents](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/) - `vector::clear`.

You should do this instead:

```
result.push_back(inner);
// std::vector<Node *> inner;
inner.clear();
```

If you need to clear something you've pushed inside a vector, you can do this:

```
vector< vector< int > > vvi;
vector< int > vi;
vi.push_back(1); // fill
vii.push_back(vi); // vii has a copy of vi as it is now.
auto & _v = vii[0]; // fetch a reference to the copy
_v.clear(); // clear it
vii[0].clear(); // same in one step
assert( vii[0].size() == 0 ); // still contains a vector at index 0 but it's empty
```

---

Notwithstanding the fact that you would be clearing vectors of *pointers* - as others have pointed out (ha) you need to be very careful not to 'lose track' of pointers.

Eg, this would be bad:

```
vector< int* > x;
x.push_back( new int(4) );
x.clear(); // leak
```

Answer (score 0):

In order of an object to go out of scope, it has to be created **INSIDE** the loop, like this for example:

```
while(1) {
  std::vector<int> v;
  ...
  // at that point 'v' will go out of scope and thus destroyed
}
```

However, when you do this:

```
std::vector<int> v;
while(1) {
  ...
  // 'v' is always the same at this point
}
```

---

You could use [std::vector::clear()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/) to reset your vector, but be careful, since you are using pointers. Unless you keeping track of the pointed objects, just clearing the vector would result to *dangling pointers*, thus *Undefined Behavior* and you don't want that to happen.

If you need to free the memory the pointers point to, then you should *first* delete the objects the pointers point to and *then* clear the vector.